# How can I update fields in Access tables at the background?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a formular `a_form` which has a data binding to my table `my_table`.
If the user clicks a button, I want to update my field `txt_mytext` from `"Hello"` to `"Hello World!"`

How can I update this field without getting the write conflict:

```
This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it. If you save the       record, you will overwrite the changes the other user made. Copying the changed to the clipboard will let you look at the values the other user entered, and then paste your changes back in if you decide to make changes.
```

I tried the folowing methods:

- Using a SQL-Statements (It's clear for me that I'm getting a write conflict using this method, since I access my table using the data binding AND the sql statement
- Using `a_form!txt_mytext = "Hello World!"`. It's not clear for my why I'm getting the write confict using this method.

Is there any third method or do I have to call `Me!Requery`, `Me!Refresh`, `Me!Dirty` ... to avoid the write conflict ?

My code in `frm_a_form` is:

```
Private Sub btn_calculate_Click()
         Forms!a_form!txt_mytext = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is you exact code? You should be updating the control, not the field.

Comment: What does this mean 'updating the control'?

Comment: Do you mean Me.Controls!txt_mytext = "Hello World" ?? This doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you were getting a write conflict.  However, in your own answer, you reported this works:

```
Forms!a_form!txt_mytext = "Hello World!"
```

Since that works, do the same thing from the click event of your command button on that form:

```
Private Sub btn_calculate_Click()
    Me!txt_mytext = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

If you want to save that change immediately, add this to the click event procedure:

```
Me.Dirty = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
Forms!a_form!txt_mytext = "Hello World!"
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70
```

I found this out randomly by googeling around e.g http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=446217

Please feel free to explain this solution or to add your own answer.